# Rails form_tag and redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi im trying to implement a simple search form in my navbar, it works, but there is a problem with it

if im in my show.html.erb view and use the search form i wont get redirected to my index.html.erb. here is my code

```
<%= form_tag("/products", method: :get) do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], {:class =>"search-query", :placeholder=>"Search"}  %>                
<% end %>
```

i want this form to redirect me completley to "products#index", thanks in advance

EDIT:

I figured it out...

i had this

```
     <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
        <%= form_tag({:controller => "products", :action => "index"}, method: :get) do %>
             <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], {:class =>"search-query", :placeholder=>"Search"}  %>                
            <% end %>
        </form>
```

i had two forms the HTML one and the helper method one.

Thanks anyways

Comment: This looks like it should work. Where is it redirecting you to now?

Comment: Do you have a submit button or code that submits the form?

Comment: it redirects to the current page im in. if im in show.html.erb and submit that form the browser just refreshes in show.html.erb with the query in the url

Comment: mmm, it dosnt has a submit button, im submiting it with ENTER

Comment: guys forget it, i found out my error, it was plain stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

i had this

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => "products", :action => "index"}, method: :get) do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], {:class =>"search-query", :placeholder=>"Search"}  %>                
        <% end %>
    </form>
```

i had two forms the HTML one and the helper method one.

Thanks anyways